# GOCD Nexus plugin don't recognize packages

Tags: nexus, continuous-deployment, go-cd

I'm using GOCD for continuous deployment. I installed the Nexus plugin and configured the repository successfuly. But when I try to make a new pipeline using the repository, the plugin can not find any package.
At first I thought the problem was my *.tar.gz* packages, but then I tried with *.rpm* package and *.jar* (maven) package, the result is always the same **No packages found**

Additional information

- GOCD version: 19.2.0-8641
- Nexus version: OSS 3.15.2-01
- go-nexus-poller-plugin version: v1.0.2